# Undefined index: mfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing_websites\upload_detail.php on line 3

Tags: php

```
Undefined index: mfile    
<html>
<head>

</head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload_imagedetail.php" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="mfile"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="msubmit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html> 
Undefined index: mfile        
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['msubmit'])){
        if($_FILES['mfile']){
            echo " Hello <br/>";
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $_FILES['mfile']['tmp_name'] . "<br/>";
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
?>
```

After submitting the form I am getting

> Undefined index: mfile in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testing_websites\upload_detail.php on line 3

Comment: Check `isset($_FILES['mfile'])` and do `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: <form action="upload_imagedetail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> missing enctype=multipart/form-data

Comment: The file getting the error is `upload_detail.php` yet the file you are sending it it to is `upload_imagedetail.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag. Please add that and try again.

```
        <form action="upload_imagedetail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="mfile"><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="msubmit">
        </form>
```

Comment: var_dump($_FILES['mImg']); giving me NULL Value but the problem of undefined index is not solved

Comment: what is the name of the file input you have given?